# How to relocation the back stack on android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I want to **relocation** the back-stack on android application.

When I press back key, I want to push history to bottom in back-stack. But I can't found Intent Flag about this.

I want to relocation back-stack on android.

[image]

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

When I press Navigate back, I want to push Activity3 in bottom of back-stack.

minimize icon (like a Youtube minimize video)
[image]

right|bottom minimize video view

Comment: I wish I could understand your question.

Comment: sorry, I will fix my question.

Comment: @DavidWasser Hello. Can you understand?

Comment: No, sorry :-( Can you give an example of what you want to do? Maybe some pictures would help if you cannot write in English.

Comment: @DavidWasser Thank you for your comment. I added a picture.

Comment: You cannot push an `Activity` to the bottom (root) of the back stack. You can move an `Activity` from anywhere in the stack to the foreground using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I should make a chatting feature on all activity in application. And chatting feature runnuing on WebViewActivity.

Comment: Webview activity can be minimization icon. This icon should be exist all activity. I did success made it as Custom View but my partner want to making as Activity.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by "minimzation icon". I still don't understand your requirements. Perhaps you can post a drawing of what you want.

Comment: @DavidWasser "minimize view" like a Youtube video.

Answer (score 0):

so basically, instead of destroying activity 3 when the back button is pressed - you want to push activity to the end of the stack? (activity 2 in foreground; activity 1 and 3 in background)

referring to your link https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

> if you start an activity that specifies the singleTask launch mode, then if an instance of that activity exists in a background task, that whole task is brought to the foreground.

basically define in the manifest "singleTask", then you override the 'onBackPress()' method to start the existing activity (e.g. activity 2). this will push activity 3 into the background instead of destroying it.

you need to remember the activity order in your stack. so you know what activity to bring to the foreground
.

the question now is how do you then exit your app if you don't want to destroy the activities?